# Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Show that $\lbrace x : f(x) \neq 0 \rbrace$ is open.

Tags: general-topology

I already have an Idea, but im not completely sure if that works. Probably you could tell me, if I am right?

Suppose $f$ is not constant, because $\mathbb{R}$ and $\emptyset$ are both open.

Let $M := \lbrace x : f(x) \neq 0 \rbrace$ and let x $\in M$. WLOG $f(x) > 0$. Define $\varepsilon := f(x) - 0 = f(x)$. Because $f$ is continuous the existence of an $\delta > 0$ such that $\vert x - y \vert < \delta \Rightarrow \vert f(x) - f(y) \vert < \varepsilon = f(x)$. Now $B_\delta(x) \subseteq M$ because $\vert f(x) \vert > \vert f(y) \vert$, especially $f(y) \neq 0$.

Is that right? Tank you already for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than the fact that $f(x)-0=f(x)$ rather than $0$, it is correct.

Alternatively, you can say that that set is open since it is equal to $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$, $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is open and $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Of course you are right. I edited my original post accordingly. Also your suggestion is way smarter and less work than mine. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to visualize what @AnotherUser said:
\begin{align*}
\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n} \mid f(x) \neq 0\} & = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n} \mid f(x) > 0\}\cup\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n} \mid f(x) < 0\}\\\\
& = f^{-1}((0,+\infty))\cup f^{-1}((-\infty,0))
\end{align*}

Once the intervals $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,+\infty)$ are open and $f$ is continuous, one concludes the desired claim.

Hopefully this contributes!